# When did people living for 900 years start to look old?

Tags: history, historical-figures, parashat-bereishit, age

In the early days of the world, the standard age of living was well into the hundreds, with many people living until they were 800 or 900. Being that people lived so long, when did they start to "look old"?

For example, would someone 100 years old look like a modern 100, or perhaps a modern 20?

Comment: Isn't there some Midrash about Avraham being the first person to age in appearance?

Comment: I've never heard it, but i'm not proficient in Midrash.

Comment: Ah [Bava Metzia 87a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=87&format=text) Kindva boring answer, no?

Comment: Interesting question! I heard something about the reason Pharaoh asked Yaakov his age was due to his aged appearance.

Comment: It still seems that the biological maturity was working at a different pace based on the ages that that had children. Unless they were all just learning in a European yeshiva.

Comment: I remember learning that Yitzchak was the first to get sick, as opposed to being in full health at the time of death.  I wouldn't be surprised if "full health" also meant no obvious signs of aging, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Jacob not Isaac, see source in my answer, unless you are thinking of a different one!

Comment: @BabySeal I was actually thinking of Yitzchak, who was going blind during the stolen-b'racha incident.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ahh interesting. I guess the gemara in BMetz does not consider blindness a sickness.

Comment: @MonicaCellio blindness is not a sickness which would lead to death (a conclusion I draw based on my other question of the word "vayigva" -- Yitzchak's death is instant and without suffering so any condition like blindness would have to be unrelated).

Comment: @Danno ah, that makes sense -- if aging is "on the way to death" then blindness would be orthogonal.

Comment: I want to answer "as soon as their children became teenagers" but that would be too flippant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Bava Metzia 87a](http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_87.html):

> Until Abraham **there was no old age**; whoever wished to speak to Abraham would speak to Isaac, and the reverse. Thereupon he prayed, and old age came into existence, as it is written, And Abraham was old and well-stricken in age.

So during the age when people lived 200+ years, they showed no signs of age.

Comment: You guys think this might be a source for the notion of ageless magical elves in other mythologies?

Comment: The only 'elves' that i know of are mentioned in the Zohar in vayikra page ten, that being the short hominid beings who are not descended from Adam and live in an underworld, are said to have a shorter life span, not longer.

Comment: What does that mean, "whoever wished to speak to Abraham would speak to Isaac, and the reverse"?

Comment: Doesn't Ber 18:11 indicate that there were signs of age, at least internal/physiological ones?

Comment: @Scimonster They looked exactly like each other, and were confused for each other. Later, when Avraham started to look old, people were able to tell the difference between them.

Comment: @Danno I think it is evident from the Talmud that external age is what was added, because Abraham was praying that he and Isaac be distinguishable? Definitely a good point though. Maybe, as with many other aggadic passages, this  has a nonliteral intent.

Comment: @user6591 I was talking about like Norse mythology. There are 'light elves' who are long lived and don't show signs of age. Maybe the myths finds it origins in early humanity, who fuilfilled those criterea!

Comment: @Danno reinforcing your point is that expounded upon phrase, which is used as a proof text, being used before Isaac was born. Reconsidering this as a valid answer...

Comment: I think it's still a valid answer. The way i understand the phrase @Danno brought is that they were old internally, but not necessarily externally visible.

Comment: According to Sfas Emed parshas Chayei Sarah year 636, Avraham's prayer for oldness means chochma, knowledge, to understand spirituality and the next world while still on this one. Apparently not a new physical reality.

Comment: @user6591 how does he understand the gemara...?

Comment: He doesn't get into that but thinking imaginatively we can say that people who wanted sage spiritual advice would end up talking to Yitzchok. Abraham prayed for that spiritual sagacity. And kalstar panim could also be understood like this. If you really want.  But it's a drasha. Just thought I'd mention it.